# I would like to help implement a self-relationship in Code First

Tags: .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first

I would like to help implement a self-relationship as shown below:

[image]

I have a class category that has a list of subcategories. How would the class and its mapping using the CODE FIRST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity

```
public class Category : Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

And the mapping

```
public class CategoryMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
{
    public CategoryMap()
    {
        HasKey(category => category.Id);

        Property(category => category.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        HasOptional(category => category.ParentCategory)
            .WithMany(category => category.SubCategories)
            .HasForeignKey(category => category.ParentId);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ViniciusSaeta Do you have an existing table for `Category`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just create a property within your `Category` class.

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Category> Categories {get;set;}
```

Comment: Make sure that ALL of your properties are virtual.

Comment: When is the error? on creation or using? If using, try this on your context: context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;